# Does the limit exist if the function is made up of only 3 points?

Tags: calculus, limits

$f(-1)=f(0)=f(1)=5$ and $f(x)$ is undefined if $x\in R$\{-1,0,1} .

Question: does $\underset{x\rightarrow0}{\lim}f(x)$ exist? My confusion comes from the fact that $f(0)$ does exist and although I remember that we do not care about the value of the function exactly at the *x*-point of interest, I'm still not sure.

I tend to think that the limit does *not* exist because $f(x)$ is undefined in the vicinity of $0$ except for the two other points.

Am I right?

Comment: $0$ should be a *limit point* of the domain, which is it not, so the limit is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit of a function in a point $x$ is a term defined on the *deleted neighbourhood* of a point IE $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)\setminus \{x\}$. Hence in the scenario you suggest the limit if not defined since the function is not defined on the deleted neighbourhood of $0$ or any other point.

Note that this immediately implies that in order for a limit to exist the function cannot be defined on a fixed amount of points.